# Can a neural network learn a function with asymptote?

Tags: neural-networks

Can a neural network learn a function with an asymptote?  For example $lim_{x \to 0}{1 \over x^2}= \infty$, so can we use a neural network to approximate ${1\over x^2}= \infty$ ?

Comment: What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

A (feedforward) neural network is a repeated application of a linear (or affine) transformation and a nonlinear elementwise "saturation" function (i.e. a function that is finitely bounded above and below). For example,

$$ f(x) = W_3\sigma(W_2 \sigma(W_1 x))  $$

where the $W_i$ are weight matrices and $\sigma$ is an elementwise saturation (neuron) function. Your question is: can we find some finite $W_i$ such that $\underset{x \to c}{\lim} f(x) = \infty$ for some finite $c$.

Obviously since $\sigma$ is a bounded function, and the last $W_i$ is just a linear (or affine) transformation, this is not possible. I mean, consider the function $z=Ay$. Can you pick $A$ such that $z$ is infinite for some bounded $y$?

A more rigorous way to give you the answer "no" is to explain the [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).

Comment: My question was being put on hold for being unclear.  But yes, jnez71, that is what I am asking.